# Horizontal line in spring layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, springlayout, jseparator

I have a program with a bunch of fields in a single panel, both labels and text fields. I needed to separate them somehow with a line to make it easier to read.

I have the panel built with `SpringLayout`. I was wondering if there is an easy way to create a horizontal line in `SpringLayout` without dividing the panel into 2, and adding a divider panel in between them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best practice would be creating another `JPanel`, but if I correctly understood your problem, maybe an alternative can be create a `JSeparator`:

```
JSeparator separator = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
separator.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,3));
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried using JSeparator but nothing was showing up, but I wasn't putting a size on it so I guess the size defaulted to 0? But doing what you said did create a horizontal line the way i needed. Thanks a bunch! :)